# How to install ubuntu-12.10-desktop along with windows 8 64bit

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, partitioning, windows-8

I have hp pavilion 15 n204tx, which came with pre-installed Ubuntu OS.
I formatted it and installed Win 8 64bit.
and created 3 + 1(system reserve) partition.

```
        50GB for win8
        50GB for Ubuntu
        remaining for my files
        and other is system reserve.
```

But now i need ubuntu-12.10-desktop also, along with win8.

Is there is a way to install ubuntu-12.10-desktop, without affecting my files and win8 on second 50GB partition.

Is the installation method is same as of  other similar questions here.

Please answer and i don't know anything about commands posted on other answers here, i just started to learn UNIX.
So kindly tell where and how to use commands, if any

Thank you

Comment: Fiesta of all, get Ubuntu 14.04. 12.10 is out of support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu is nice at installing alongside another os. During the installation it will ask about win8 or partitions. At this point select your ubuntu partition, make some of this swap, the remaining the root of your filesystem (/). All should go ok. Two points, firstly i would resequence your partitions for microsoft's sake go for something like this.
Windows c:
More windows partitions.
Swap (about 2-3 times RAM i think)
Ubuntu (root i.e. /)
User data (/home)
Recovery partition.
Secondly win8 machines have a bios option to only allow ms win8 on this machine, this needs to be set to allow another os.

Comment: ok.. Please consider this coz i don't know anything about it...   can you tell me how partition table i need to create. p like /dev /boot or anything else please see : http://i62.tinypic.com/j65vg2.jpg

Comment: You only need / and swap. But / swap /home will be enough to have a disaster recovery resilient setup. It looks like under 14.04 say 3700 mb for /.

Comment: done! but at the end it ask me to erase previous Ubuntu (system default, my laptop came with pre installed ubuntu), and i don't want that...                                                                     please help

Answer (score 0):

You can install ubuntu or any linux distribution without affecting files in other partition. Here is the link how you can install ubuntu alongside windows
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

a) Go To the Link: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/

b) Download and Save suitable .iso image in locale drive

c) Create bootable USB/ DVD drive: for USB use "Startup Disc Creator", for DVD just burn the image using any burner like "K3B"

Step 2:

Insert USB/DVD Device > Reboot > Enter BIOS Setput > Set Boot Device Priority > Save & Exit

Step 3:

Install Ubuntu OS > Select "Install Ubuntu Along Side Windows" > Reboot & Verify